# Creating byte array without initializing with 0s

Tags: c#, .net, streaming, clr, .net-standard

For a network related framework I need a lot of `byte[]` buffers to read and write data. When creating a new byte array, the CLR will initialize all values with `0`. For buffers used with streams, this seems to be unnecessary overhead:

```
var buffer = new byte[65536];

var read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Is there a way to create a `byte[]` array without initializing all values with `0` in C#? Probably by invoking a `malloc` style method? I'm sure this question has been answered, but I didn't find any clues to start with.

Comment: No there isn't. What you could do is use a **pool** of buffers, so the overhead only occurs once. You will then need to ensure that your logic handles the fact that the array may have 'old' data in it.

Comment: While reusing arrays is a good start here, I suspect you may also want to look into "pipelines", which would give you all the advantages of `ArrayPool<byte>`, but also *lots more*, including a better consumption model, and the ability to use non-contiguous buffers; pipelines is the API that underpins the impressive Kestrel performance. You say "network related framework" - in that case, Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial (nuget) has a Socket<=>Pipe bridge for direct consumption, and a Stream<=>Pipe bridge if you need intermediaries (for example, `SslStream`)

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thank you very much! Especially the `PositionOf` and `Advance` of the API seem to be the dream when it comes to tokenizing / parsing requests. I'll have a look at pipelines when implementing HTTP/2.

Comment: @Gene note: HTTP/2 (client and server) is being added as part of .NET Core 3; if you want more details / examples of using pipelines, I have blogged about it extensively

Comment: @MarcGravell: Well, the idea of the project is to implement the HTTP protocol myself, mainly for educational reasons. But I will certainly look at the interfaces there. It's still a long road till 7 million requests per second :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills) link, I stumbled upon the `ArrayPool<T>` of [System.Buffers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Buffers/):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var pool = ArrayPool<byte>.Create();

    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    Parallel.For(0, 1000000, (i) =>
    {
        //DoSomethingWithBuffers();
        DoSomethingWithPooledBuffers(pool);
    });

    Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

private static int DoSomethingWithBuffers()
{
    var buffer = new byte[65536];
    return buffer.Length;
}

private static int DoSomethingWithPooledBuffers(ArrayPool<byte> pool)
{
    var buffer = pool.Rent(65536);

    var length = buffer.Length;

    pool.Return(buffer);

    return length;
}
```

Which makes quite a difference (release mode):

- DoSomethingWithBuffers: 3264ms
- DoSomethingWithPooledBuffers: 470ms